# VIM C /* comments * on new line if */ not present

Tags: c, vim

A long time ago on a different machine when I used to write C code in VIM, I had something enabled so that when I started a comment with `/*` and hit enter before `*/` was typed, VIM would put a `*` and space it out nicely.  What is that and how do I get it back?  I want it to automagically do this:

```
/* some comments
 * <-- VIM put this " * " here */
```

General suggestions to make VIM cooler welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's `r` and `o` in `formatoptions`. See [`:help fo-table`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#fo-table)

> ```
> letter  meaning when present in 'formatoptions'
>
> r       Automatically insert the current comment leader after hitting           
>         <Enter> in Insert mode.                                                 
> o       Automatically insert the current comment leader after hitting 'o' or    
>         'O' in Normal mode.
> ```